# By using custom color as Background JFrame stops showing any JPanels

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

Hi I've got a new problem! While I tried to change a JPanels background by:

```
pnl1.setBackground(new Color(0,150,50));
```

the JFrame stops showing any JPanels. Should I use a Layout? If yes which and how?

I don't know whether it's a bug because it doesn't tell me about an error and it works by using "Color.GREEN".. but watch it yourself.

```
    package GUI;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.TextField;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final int width = 1520;
    public static final int height = 860;
    private Color c_green= new Color(0,153,51);
    private Color c_blue_friends = new Color(30,144,155);

    JPanel pnl1;
        JScrollPane sp;
        JPanel pnl1_01;
            JTextField tf1;

        JPanel pnl1_02;
        JPanel pnl1_03;

    JPanel pnl2;


    JPanel pnl3;


    JPanel pnl4;
    JPanel pnl5;
    JPanel pnl6;


    public MainFrame(){
        setTitle("HackMey");
        setSize(width,height);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setLayout(null);
        setVisible(true);

        pnl1 = new JPanel();
        pnl1.setBounds(0, 0, width / 2, height);
        pnl1.setBackground(Color.black);
        pnl1.setLayout(null);


            sp = new JScrollPane();
            sp.setBounds(width / 2 - 10, 0, 10, height);
            sp.setBorder(null);
            sp.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            sp.setVisible(true);

            pnl1_01 = new JPanel();
            pnl1_01.setBounds(0, height - height / 8, width / 2, height / 8);
            pnl1_01.setBackground(Color.gray);
            pnl1_01.setLayout(null);
            pnl1_01.setVisible(false);

            tf1 = new JTextField();
            tf1.setBorder(null);
            tf1.setBounds(0, height - height/10, width/2 -10, height / 10);
            tf1.setBackground(Color.black);
            tf1.setForeground(c_green);
            tf1.setVisible(true);

        pnl1.add(sp);
        pnl1.add(pnl1_01);  
        pnl1.add(tf1);
        pnl1.setVisible(true);

        pnl2 = new JPanel();
        pnl2.setBounds(width / 2, 0, width / 2, height / 4);
        pnl2.setBackground(c_green);
        pnl2.setLayout(null);
        pnl2.setVisible(true);


        pnl3 = new JPanel();
        pnl3.setBounds(width / 2, height / 4, width / 2, height / 4);
        pnl3.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        pnl3.setLayout(null);
        pnl3.setVisible(true);


        pnl4 = new JPanel();
        pnl4.setBounds(width / 2, 2* (height / 4), width / 2, height / 4);
        pnl4.setBackground(c_blue_friends);
        pnl4.setLayout(null);
        pnl4.setVisible(true);


        pnl5 = new JPanel();
        pnl5.setBounds(width / 2, 3* (height / 4), width / 4, height / 4);
        pnl5.setBackground(Color.RED);
        pnl5.setLayout(null);
        pnl5.setVisible(true);


        pnl6 = new JPanel();
        pnl6.setBounds(3*(width / 4), 3* (height / 4), width / 4, height / 4);
        pnl6.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        pnl6.setLayout(null);
        pnl6.setVisible(true);

        add(pnl1);
        add(pnl2);
        add(pnl3);
        add(pnl4);
        add(pnl5);
        add(pnl6);

        setVisible(true);
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainFrame obj = new MainFrame();

    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want the program to do?

Comment: Until now nothing else than givin me a nice outlay.. later on I want it to work as chatting program but I'm not close at all..

Answer (score 0):

The JFrame is not being refreshed after you added the elements. Try moving the `setVisible(true)` line to the end, after adding all the JPanels.

**Update**
The JTextField is shown on the screen. It is not visible because the parent `JPanel` and the `JTextField` have the same background color, `Color.black`. Set different background colors to the parent JPanel and the JTextField and you'll be able to see the `JTextField`. 
And, hardcoding width and height of the window is not a good practice. Your program may have to run on other computers with different screen sizes.
So, consider setting the width and height of the window of your application to match the screen size of the computer. This can be done using the following two lines :

```
public static final int width = (int)java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth();
public static final int height = (int)java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight();
```

Consider using [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html), instead of the AbsoluteLayout. `GridBagLayout` is considered the most flexible and powerful LayoutManager. Learn more on `GridBagLayout` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Comment: Ok thank you very much this worked but I've got a new issue.. it's again the same but it's caused by the jtextfield.. why and how could I fix this?

Comment: And I don't even have to add the jtextfield to any panel so that it happens and if I do so it doesn't change anything

Comment: @leon8171 can you be more clear? Can you edit the question to add what problem you're facing? What issue is caused by the JTextField? Please try to add the code to the question, that you think is not behaving as expected.

Comment: Done! Thank you for spending your time ;) Nothing is working when I try to initiate the JTextfield..